# Возврат переменной, а не строки

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, flask

Пишу чат бота для вк. В гайде на хабре используется flask. Если запрос послан не из вк, то возвращает 'not vk'. Я захотел, чтобы мне вернуло data, которая посылается вместе с запросом. Но выбивает ошибку. Что я делаю не так?

```
# A very simple Flask Hello World app for you to get started with...
import vk

from flask import Flask, request, json
confirmation_token = ''
token = ''
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def processing():
    #Распаковываем json из пришедшего POST-запроса
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    #Вконтакте в своих запросах всегда отправляет поле типа
    if 'type' not in data.keys():
        return 'not vk'
    if data['type'] == 'confirmation':
        return confirmation_token
    elif data['type'] == 'message_new':
        session = vk.Session()
        api = vk.API(session, v=5.50)
        user_id = data['object']['user_id']
        api.messages.send(access_token=token, user_id=str(user_id), message='lel')
        # Сообщение о том, что обработка прошла успешно
        return 'ok'
```

Вместо not vk запрашиваю data и всё ломается.

```
# A very simple Flask Hello World app for you to get started with...
import vk

from flask import Flask, request, json
confirmation_token = ''
token = ''
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def processing():
    #Распаковываем json из пришедшего POST-запроса
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    #Вконтакте в своих запросах всегда отправляет поле типа
    if 'type' not in data.keys():
        return data.keys()
    if data['type'] == 'confirmation':
        return confirmation_token
    elif data['type'] == 'message_new':
        session = vk.Session()
        api = vk.API(session, v=5.50)
        user_id = data['object']['user_id']
        api.messages.send(access_token=token, user_id=str(user_id), message='lel')
        # Сообщение о том, что обработка прошла успешно
        return 'ok'
```

Ошибка выглядит так(В postman):

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> ## Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: Вы возвращаете не переменную, а значение. В данном случае вы возвращаете набор ключей словаря в виде объекта класса `dict_keys`. Вы уверены, что вызывающий функцию код знает, что с такими объектами делать? Что конкретно вы хотите этим кодом сказать?

Comment: Я просто хотел, чтобы при запросе не из вк мне возвращало тот json который я отправил.

Comment: @Dinbytes, тогда просто возвращайте `request.data`, а не `data.keys()`. Если нужно вернуть список ключей, то переводите все в строку, например так: `', '.join(data.keys())`.

Comment: Можно попробовать json.dump(data.keys())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо

```
return data.keys()
```

Возвращать

```
return flask.jsonify(data.keys())
```

В таком случае он будет форматировать в json, и отправлять ответ.
А вообще было бы неплохо увидеть stacktrace flask'а на такой запрос